# Cypher, create unique relationship for one node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to add a "created by" relationship on nodes in my database. Any node should be able of having this relationship but there can never be more than one.

Right now my query looks something like this:

```
MATCH (u:User {email: 'my@mail.com'})
MERGE (n:Node {name: 'Node name'})
ON CREATE SET n.name='Node name', n.attribute='value'
CREATE UNIQUE (n)-[:CREATED_BY {date: '2015-02-23'}]->(u)
RETURN n
```

As I have understood Cypher there is no way to achieve what I want, the current query will only make sure there are no unique relationships based on TWO nodes, not ONE. So, this will create more CREATED_BY relationships when run for another User and I want to limit the outgoing CREATED_BY relationship to just one for all nodes.

Is there a way to achieve this without running multiple queries involving program logic?

Thanks.

**Update**

I tried to simplyfy the query by removing implementation details, if it helps here's the updated query based on cybersams response.

```
MERGE (c:Company {name: 'Test Company'}) 
ON CREATE SET c.uuid='db764628-5695-40ee-92a7-6b750854ebfa', c.created_at='2015-02-23 23:08:15', c.updated_at='2015-02-23 23:08:15' 
WITH c
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)
WHERE NOT (c)-[:CREATED_BY]-() 
CREATE (c)-[:CREATED_BY {date: '2015-02-23 23:08:15'}]->(u:User {token: '32ba9d2a2367131cecc53c310cfcdd62413bf18e8048c496ea69257822c0ee53'})  
RETURN c
```

Still not working as expected.

**Update #2**

I ended up splitting this into two queries.

The problem I found was that there was two possible outcomes as I noticed.

1. The `CREATED_BY` relationship was created and `(n)` was returned using `OPTIONAL MATCH`, this relationship would always be created if it didn't already exist between `(n)` and `(u)`, so when changing the email attribute it would re-create the relationship.
2. The Node `(n)` was not found (because of not using `OPTIONAL MATCH` and the `WHERE NOT (c)-[:CREATED_BY]-()` clause), resulting in no relationship created (yay!) but without getting the `(n)` back the `MERGE` query looses all it's meaning I think.

My Solution was the following two queries:

```
MERGE (n:Node {name: 'Name'})
ON CREATE SET
SET n.attribute='value'
WITH n
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r:CREATED_BY]-()
RETURN c, r
```

Then I had program logic check the value of `r`, if there was no relationship I would run the second query.

```
MATCH (n:Node {name: 'Name'})
MATCH (u:User {email: 'my@email.com'})
CREATE UNIQUE (n)-[:CREATED_BY {date: '2015-02-23'}]->(u)
RETURN n
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find any real solution to combining this in one single query with Cypher. Sam, thanks! I've selected your answer even though it didn't quite solve my problem, but it was very close.

Comment: I think you want to remove the `OPTIONAL` part otherwise the `CREAT` always fires and always created the user node.

Comment: You're right Dave, of course. Problem is I also always want to return the (n) regardless of if the CREATE_BY relationship was created or not. I'm starting to think it's impossible to make a query like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
MERGE (n:Node {name: 'Node name'})
ON CREATE SET n.attribute='value'
WITH n
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT (n)-[:CREATED_BY]->()
CREATE UNIQUE (n)-[:CREATED_BY {date: '2015-02-23'}]->(:User {email: 'my@mail.com'})
RETURN n;
```

I've removed the starting `MATCH` clause (because I presume you want to create a `CREATED_BY` relationship even when that `User` does not yet exist in the DB), and  simplified the `ON CREATE` to remove the redundant setting of the `name` property.

I have also added an `OPTIONAL MATCH` that will only match an `n` node that does not already have an outgoing `CREATED_BY` relationship, followed by a `CREATE UNIQUE` clause that fully specifies the `User` node.

Comment: Thanks, however this seems to recreate the User node.

Comment: Thanks again for your quick responses, but I still can't get this to avoid creating multiple CREATED_BY relationships. Seems like it should be such a simple query, but I can't wrap my head around it right now. Will sleep on this and try some more tomorrow.

Comment: I think my question is impossible to solve actually. Thinking about it... as long as we filter the (n) node based on a relationship the node it self will never be returned, right? So, either it returns the (n) AND creates the CREATED_BY relationship or it doesn't return anything. I also, of course, want the (n) to be returned.

Comment: The `n` node is either found or created by the `MERGE` clause (and then reused by the `OPTIONAL MATCH`), so it will always exist. I have verified that there is no problem.